# Conditional independence in posterior predictive distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian

The derivation of posterior predictive distribution has the following steps -

$\begin{split}p(\tilde y\mid y) = &\int p(\tilde y, \theta\mid y)~\mathsf d\theta \\ = &\int p(\tilde y\mid\theta, y)\,p(\theta\mid y)~\mathsf d\theta \\ = &\int p(\tilde y\mid\theta)\,p(\theta\mid y)~\mathsf d\theta\end{split}$

where

- $\tilde y$ : new data for prediction
- $y$ : observed data
- $\theta$ : unknown parameter.

$p(\tilde y\mid\theta, y)$ reduces to $p(\tilde y\mid\theta)$ due to conditional independence.

Can you explain why this is the case? The way I have convinced myself is that given $\tilde y$ is conditioned on $\theta$, the aspects of observed data $y$ is captured through $\theta$ and given $\tilde y\mid θ$ and $y$ are independent we can drop $y$ from the equation.

Is there a more formal explanation for this? Also why doesn't this equation reduce to $p(\tilde y\mid θ) \cdot p(y)$?

Comment: The underlying thought is that each observation is i.i.d. (independently identically distributed, given the underlying distribution type and parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unknown parameter $\theta$ is selected such that the prior and posterior data will be independent when its value is given.   That is such that $p(y,\tilde y\mid\theta)=p(y\mid \theta)\,p(\tilde y\mid\theta)$.

So, adding a few steps:

$\begin{align}p(\tilde y\mid y) = &\int p(\tilde y, \theta\mid y)~\mathsf d\theta &&\textsf{Law of Total Probability}\\[1ex] = &\int p(\tilde y\mid\theta, y)\,p(\theta\mid y)~\mathsf d\theta&&\textsf{Definition of Conditional Probability} \\[1ex]=&\int\dfrac{p(y,\tilde y\mid\theta)\;p(\theta\mid y)}{p(y\mid\theta)\hspace{10ex}}~\mathsf d\theta&&\textsf{Definition of Conditional Probability}\\[1ex]=& \int \dfrac{p(y\mid\theta)\,p(\tilde y\mid\theta)\;p(\theta\mid y)}{p(y\mid\theta)\hspace{16ex}}~\mathsf d\theta&&\text{Via the Conditional Independence} \\[1ex] = &\int p(\tilde y\mid\theta)\,p(\theta\mid y)~\mathsf d\theta && \text{Canceling the common factor.}\end{align}$

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put out the steps. I still don't understand the 3rd equality based on Conditional probability. Could you explain it plz ?

Comment: $p(y,\tilde y\mid \theta)=p(\tilde y\mid\theta, y)\,p(y\mid \theta)$ by definition, so $p(\tilde y\mid \theta, y)=p(y,\tilde y\mid\theta)/p(y\mid \theta)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Sorry, I am a little bit confused about $p(a,b|c)$. Is it $p(a,b|c)=p(a,b.c)/p(c)$?

Comment: @Hermi Yes, that is how the definition is applied.$$p(a,b,c)~{=p(a,b\mid c)\,p(c)\\=p(a\mid b,c)\,p(b\mid c)\,p(c)\\=p(a\mid b,c)\,p(b,c)\\\text{et cetera}}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Do you mean $p(a|b,c)=p(a,b,c)/p(b,c)$? But not $p(a|b,c)=p(a,b,c)/p(b)$?

Comment: @Hermi Yes.  $p(a\mid b,c)=\dfrac{p(a,b,c)}{p(b,c)}$, and $p(a, c\mid b)=\dfrac{p(a,b,c)}{p(b)}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Can you help me see this question?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3824277/how-to-show-that-the-following-identities-about-conditional-probability How to compute $E(y^*|y)?$ Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st equality is true since through this fact: if $B_{1},B_{2},...,B_{n}$ partition A separately and independently then $P(A)=P(A\cap B_{1})+P(A\cap B_{2})+...+P(A\cap B_{n})$. The 2nd equality is the same conditioning through $P(x,y)=P(x)P(y|x)$ and the 3rd one is a Markov chain as ~y$\to\theta\to y$

Comment: What do you by a Markov chain in this context ?